# Non-capturing group still captures input

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Date format that can be input in the following format:

```
December, 13, 2016 
December , 13 , 2016
December    ,13    ,   2016 
.
.
.
```

So I am trying to match and capture all those input events, to eventually get a result like this:

```
December 13 2016
```

My RegEx looks like this:

```
str.match([a-zA-Z]+(?: |,)*[0-9]{1,2}(?: |,)*[0-9]+$)
```

Trust me, I have tried searching for a solution all over the web before posting a question, but with no prevail. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: You want to transform the string `"December    ,13    ,   2016 "` into the string `"December 13 2016"` ? Why not just `.replace(/[\s,]+/g, " ")` ?

Comment: If you just want to replace all non-letter/digits, you may use `s.trim().replace(/\W+/g, " ")` (or `s.trim().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, " ")`).

Comment: @DenysSéguret Well, that was a simple solution. I forgot about the `/g` option. I will check if I should use your solution or @nu11p01n73R . Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to capture the part that you want to extract. For example,

```
matches = "December    ,13    ,   2016".match(/([a-zA-Z]+)[ ,]*([0-9]{1,2})[ ,]*([0-9]+)$/)
console.log(matches[1] + ' ' + matches[2] + ' ' + matches[3])
// December 13 2016
```

- `([a-zA-Z]+)` Captures the month name to `matches[1]`.
- `([0-9]{1,2})` Captures the date.
- `([0-9]+)` Captures the year.
- `[ ,]*` which is same as `(?: |,)`, but without a group using character classes.

Comment: Well, that solves all my problems I think. @DenysSéguret also had a great suggestion. I will see which solution suits me the most. Thank you for untwining my mind this morning.

Comment: @Luminance You are welcome. :) If  you are sure that the string contains ***only*** month name date and year, then you can replace the space `\s` and `,` with single space, as mentioned in the comment.